# Azure Service Bus Message Auto forwarding with Java

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-java-sdk

Am looking to implement auto forwarding between two topics in the same namespace as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding) in Java. I did not find an equivalent of *ForwardTo* property which is in C# for Java.

```
SubscriptionDescription srcSubscription = new SubscriptionDescription (srcTopic, srcSubscriptionName);
srcSubscription.ForwardTo = destTopic;
namespaceManager.CreateSubscription(srcSubscription));
```

Is there a way to do this using the Java SDK?
The SubscriptionDescription for Java does not seem to have the same properties as C# libraries.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem for me was the azure service bus sdk version for Java I was using. The most updated stable version is 1.2.8 which does not provide management package. Upgrading to 2.0.0-Preview-5 and implementing as such worked for me.

```
SubscriptionDescription subscriptionDescription = new SubscriptionDescription(topic.name(), subscriptionId)
subscriptionDescription.setForwardTo(topic.name())
```

Comment: I am still checking if I can find a workaround to set up auto forwarding using 1.2.8, but no luck so far